# Alias in css dont work in vite.config.ts?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, vite

I have installed a library in my React project, and within the main.tsx file, I'm importing its CSS: `import '@lib/ui/assets/css/main.css';`

However, within this CSS, there are some imports like:

```css
@import "~antd/dist/antd.css";
@import "~react-grid-layout/css/styles.css";
@import "~react-resizable/css/styles.css";
@import "~react-perfect-scrollbar/dist/css/styles.css";
```

Because of this, it's complaining that it can't find these CSS files since it's trying to look for them at the root of my project, while the correct path would be to look inside the node_modules folder.

How do I set up an alias for this? I tried the following, but it didn't work:

```js
import { defineConfig, loadEnv } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import tsconfigPaths from 'vite-tsconfig-paths'

export default ({ mode }: any) => {
  const env = loadEnv(mode, process.cwd(), "");
  return defineConfig({
    plugins: [react(), tsconfigPaths()],
    resolve: {
      alias: [
        { find: '~', replacement: 'node_modules' },
      ],
    },
    define: {
      "process.env": env,
    },
    css: {
      preprocessorOptions: {
        less: {
          javascriptEnabled: true,
          additionalData: '@root-entry-name: default;',
        },
      },
    },
  })
}
```